# Patch notes for Playstation

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, ps4

Where can I find patch notes and system update history for the PlayStation systems?

Comment: please comment since you`re down-voting? feedback is always appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I wanted to say that I usually use Wikipedia to find out what's changed between versions. Simply querrying `[platform] system software` usually does the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PS3:** [PlayStation 3 System Software Update History](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps3)

**PS4:** [PlayStation 4 System Software Update History](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps4/)

**PS VITA**: [PlayStation Vita System Software Update History](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps-vita)

**PSP**: [PlayStation Portable Software Update History](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/psp)

*System updates can be found under Help -> System Updates*